# Adobe Air - Save window size and position

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm trying to write a XML file to save the position and size of the app window in it. I'm running into this error:

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. MainTimeline/setupWindow()

AS:

```
import flash.display.NativeWindowInitOptions;
import flash.display.NativeWindowSystemChrome;
import flash.display.NativeWindowType;
import flash.display.NativeWindow;


function setupWindow(e:Event = null):void
{
    gotoLastPosition();
    this.nativeWindow.addEventListener( Event.CLOSING, saveAppPosition );
}

function saveAppPosition(e:Event = null):void
{
    var xml:XML = new XML('<position x="' + this.nativeWindow.x + '" y="' + this.nativeWindow.y + '" width="' + this.width + '" height="' + this.height + '"/>');

    var f:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("appPosition.xml");
    var s:FileStream = new FileStream();
    try
    {
        s.open(f,flash.filesystem.FileMode.WRITE);
        s.writeUTFBytes(xml.toXMLString());
    }
    catch (e:Error)
    {
        //trace(error( e ));
    }
    finally
    {
        s.close();
    }
}

function gotoLastPosition():void
{
    var f:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("appPosition.xml");
    if (f.exists)
    {
        var s:FileStream = new FileStream();
        try
        {
            s.open(f,flash.filesystem.FileMode.READ);
            var xml:XML = XML(s.readUTFBytes(s.bytesAvailable));

            this.nativeWindow.x = xml. @ x;
            this.nativeWindow.y = xml. @ y;
            this.width = xml. @ width;
            this.height = xml. @ height;
        }
        finally
        {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}


setupWindow()
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: ...you have `setupWindow()` sitting at the bottom of your code, not encased in any functional block?

Comment: It's sitting at the bottom not encased in any functionl block. I'm also not sure if I should use **this.nativeWindow.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING, saveAppPosition);** or **NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.EXITING, saveAppPosition);**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **call to setupWindow()** that is causing the error, not the **saveAppPosition** method. It is executed as soon as your file is processed and **nativeWindow** is probably not yet ready.

Move **setupWindow()** call into a method (FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE handler for instance) and try again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm building the app in Adobe Flash CS 5. I tried this "on launch" event but the error still appears: `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvokeEvent);
//
function onInvokeEvent(invocation:InvokeEvent):void {
setupWindow()
}
`

Comment: Event.ACTIVATE should work I suppose (presuming that your window is default one).

Comment: I tried that and the same error comes up. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: As I told you, I think nativeWindow is undefined. Try to put a breakpoint in setupWindow() so you can confirm it. gotoLastPosition() shouldn't work either. If that is not the case, please provide more info.

Comment: You're right. How can I fix it? I don't understand why it's undefinded.

Comment: Create new project and isolate this problem so you can solve it. If you manage to reproduce it in a test project, post the code here and I'll be glad help you.

Comment: This is the code I created in Adobe Flash CS 5 for publishing as Air 2.5 desktop app: http://pastebin.com/SpVcpBdz Any help is appreciated!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nhfnVQfu should work but you shouldn't put all your code directly in flash timeline, try to find some tutorials on flash/AIR and move your code to classes. HTH